# In my system details my graphics line is blank

Tags: nvidia

I tried updating my drivers and I typed these following commands into a terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

However now my graphics space is empty and I cannot play my games without it crashing is there any way to fix this/undo it ?

Answer (score 0):

To undo those commands, you can try:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall nvidia-current
```